# Duration - what does PT2M1.06234S mean?

Tags: java, duration

I am using `Duration` and it prints me

> PT2M1.06234S

Does that mean that the duration represents **2 minutes and 1.06 seconds**?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does that mean that the duration represents 2 minutes and 1.06 seconds?

Yes.

This format is defined in **ISO 8601**. Read more about it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations). From there:

> - `P` is the duration designator (for period) placed at the start of the duration representation.
>
>   - `Y` the number of years.
>   - `M` the number of months.
>   - `W` the number of weeks.
>   - `D` the number of days.
> - `T` is the time designator that precedes the time components of the representation.
>
>   - `H` the number of hours.
>   - `M` the number of minutes.
>   - `S` the number of seconds.